# Understand tar and ssh backup

Tags: linux, ssh, tar, cat

Hello everybody i'm copying a folder from a computer to another usign tar and SSH, with the next command, but i don´t understand how 
**cat ->** 
are working. Someone could help me to understand it well?

ssh systemmanager@127.233.117.43 “tar czvpPf - /home/systemmanager/Desktop/test” | cat -> /home/debian/Desktop/backupPrueba.tar.gz

thx

Comment: `cat ->` is actually `cat -` and `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is "pipe", meaning stream the output of the previous command as input to the next.

`-` means take arguments from stdin, in this case from the return value of the piped statement.

`>` is simple file redirection. Redirect the command's normal output (to stdout) to a file named by whatever follows this operator.

The fact that `->` are run together is irrelevant. It is two separate operators.